# Find and Replace Python

Tags: python, pandas, replace, find

I am working with pandas and a rather large excel document. My goal is to find and replace particular characters in a string and replace them with nothing, essentially removing the characters. The strings are in a particular column.  Below you will see the code that I have created to find and replace, however python is not giving me an error message, and when I checked the saved file nothing has changed. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('2020.csv')

(df1.loc[(df1['SKU Code'].str.contains ('-DG'))])

dfDGremoved = (df1.loc[(df1['SKU Code'].str.contains('-DG'))].replace('-DG',''))

dfDGremoved.to_csv('2020DRAFT.csv')
```

Comment: Why check to see if the string contains what you're replacing. Just replace it first. Does this not work: `df1['SKU Code'] = df1['SKU Code'].replace('-DG', '')`. and then just `df1.to_csv('2020DRAFT.csv')`

Comment: The line `(df1.loc[(df1['SKU Code'].str.contains ('-DG'))])` doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit overengineered, Python's `replace` method ignores strings which do not contain the substring you want to replace, so the `contains` call is unnecessary. Creating a second dataframe is also unnecessary, `pandas` can deal with in-place substitutions.

To achieve the result you want, you can use a [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), which applies a function to every element in a Series (which a single column from a DataFrame is), combined to a [lambda function](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('2020.csv')
df1['SKU Code'] = df1['SKU Code'].map(lambda x: x.replace('-DG', '')
df1.to_csv('2020DRAFT.csv')
```

Unpacking this a bit:

```
df1['SKU Code'] = df1['SKU Code'].map(lambda x: x.replace('-DG', '')
  |                     |          |         └─ Create a nameless function which 
  |                     |          |            takes a string and removes '-DG'
  |                     |          |            from it 
  |                     |          |
  |                     |          └─ ...and run this function on every element...
  |                     |
  |                     └─ ... of the 'SKU Code' column in df1...
  |
  └── ... Then store the results in that same column
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.Series.str.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html). It performs regex replace.

```
dfDGremoved = df1.copy()
dfDGremoved['SKU Code'] = dfDGremoved['SKU Code'].str.replace('-DG','')
dfDGremoved.to_csv('2020DRAFT.csv')
```